# Is it bad practice to have a switch within forEach with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, foreach, switch-statement

Is it bad practice to have a switch within forEach using Javascript?

```
book.forEach(function (getBook, i) {
  switch (getBook) {
  case path:
    string = 'some html';
    break;
  };
});
```

My understanding is that this would create a switch for every instance of getBook. Let's say there are 100 of those. Then I have 100 separate switches. Is that bad?

Most importantly, does anyone have a better way to do this? It seems like it would be better to only have one switch as opposed to a whole bunch.

Comment: For a better solution, you might want to add what you're doing with some more code.

Comment: 100 switches? That's pretty crazy. I think you should consider server-sided processing with a database, in that case.

Comment: Using an object as a lookup table is probably much more optimized than 100 switches that you're repeatedly using and it probably results in a lot less code too.

Comment: You don't have 100 switches, you have one, and it's called 100 times. That's nothing. I think some people misunderstood this for a switch with 100 _cases_, which would be something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this example, adapting your current code, you can do something like -

```
bookActions = {}; 

bookActions['path'] = function() { // or the real way you're loading these
    // other code to generate that you would have had in 
    // the switch case
    return 'some html'; 
};
```

and then later, once you had your 100 or so cases as before, you could

```
book.forEach(function(getBook, i) { 
    if (bookActions[getBook]) { 
        string = bookActions[getBook](); 
    }
});
```

In this way, I am using a literal object as a mapping between a string (`getBook` in your code) and a function (the body of the switch cases).

Comment: Is looking up an object hash better than a switch ? I really wonder. A `switch` is just a fancy `if`, it's very fast. Looking up object properties is not as fast.

Comment: @Greg Ultimately I would boil it down to *do I need that performance?* If I had a have a hot loop and it came down to a dynamic functional approach or a if / switch, I'd write both and test. Otherwise, prefer the functional approach because I don't have to mess with it later.

Comment: that's also a matter of preference I guess. Switches are more readable to my eyes.

Comment: @Greg: for 100 cases and definitely for 1000 it will become faster, as JS lookup in the object is hash-based and each object at the core is a hashmap. The question when exactly hashmap lookup will be faster than a bunch of ifs and gotos in machine code varies greatly though.

Comment: I decided to make this the answer, because it was more applicable to the actual question asked here.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the switch is very long, say, longer than 5-10 cases, it is fine to do it like in your example. JavaScript runs such routines in a single thread so there is no win from more advanced functional techniques. Purely for code maintenance though, if you have more than a dozen cases, it would make sense to use a set of functions and map them into an object. In fact, many JavaScript patterns are built on such technique, mostly for various routers. For example, look at [Backbone router](http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/). Notice, how you can even templetize the case discriminators (route paths).

Calling such routes is easy (approximate idea, as the code in the question is not complete):

```
if (routes[book.path]) routes[book.path].apply(self, args)
```

however, if you want to use routing templates, you will need to iterate over all your mappings somewhat like this:

```
for (route in routes)  {
  if (matches(route,book.path)) routes[route].apply(self, args)
}
```

Comment: You pretty much hit the nail on the head. I'm still trying to understand how to fit it in with my exact code, which I didn't share because it's quite a bit longer. Thanks for taking the time to help me.